# MultipleWizzards in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Today i have a WebForms project. The project has to be rewritten (from VB to C#) and we have to decide to maintain in WebForms or do-it in MVC.

The project contains about 120 Wizards with (3 step each) witch are now a single aspx page with multiview inside.

What I've seen so far for wizards in MVC the solution is to have a view for each the steps in the wizard.

My point is: if today i have 120 wizards witch represents 120 .aspx pages, if i change it to MVC i wold have 120 * 3 views witch is quite large number of "pages".

Even tho i would have to organize it in areas to maintain it organized (today i use folders).

Can you give your opinion please??!?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create 120 wizards containing 3 pages each, there probably will be some "overlap" in some of the steps across those wizards.

My approach would be to identify all unique views and create an engine that would render the views based on configurable metadata whilst keeping track of the data entered by the user.

The key part of it all would be maintainability, i for example would hate maintaining 360 pages ;)

Comment: All views are different because they have different validation rules etc.

Comment: Validation rules have imho nothing to do with views, views render the interface, validation rules are handled in a different layer in your application. Views only display the validation results.